# Is this really a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm a student in the French equivalent of college, and I had a question about something I saw in an old competitive exam.
It was stated : "Let $F$ be the $\mathbb{C}$-vector space composed of the functions $f : \begin{array}{rcl} \mathbb{R} & \longrightarrow & \mathbb{C} \\ x & \longmapsto & x^k\rho^x e^{i\theta x}\end{array}\ \ \ $   where $k \in \{0, 1, 2\}$, $\rho \in ]0, +\infty[$, $\theta \in ]0, 2\pi ]$."

I suppose it is meant to be a vector space for $+$ and not for $\times$. Nevertheless, the exam paper admitted it was a vector space, without demonstrating it, and without even specifying whether it was additive or multiplicative. But I have some doubts about it : $F$ does not even seem to contain the identity element for $+$, which would be the function $\tilde 0$. It looks like it could be a vector space for the operator $\times$ though...

Does anyone agree ? Could someone explain this to me ? Maybe I'm completely wrong but I'm not sure about it either...

Comment: Maybe the old problem meant to ask about the vector space spanned by those functions?  Do you have the original French wording at hand?

Comment: @Atmos yeahh, it's the CCP 2015 Maths n°2

Comment: @kimchilover   http://www.maths-france.fr/MathSpe/Problemes/CCP/2015/CCP_2015_MP_M2_Enonce.pdf

Comment: @kimchi lover Damn that's it ! The french wording is completely awful but it was specified later on that $F$ was the vector space of the functions that are linear combinations of those functions... I asked three other students in my class and no one had noticed it ! x)

Comment: The joy of prepa, good luck for this year, I took it last year

Comment: @Atmos Thanks :) It's a DM but it's quite easy and this question was just bugging me... In which prepa were you ? And what school are you in now ?

Comment: You totally misstated the question! My French is very weak, but it's clear even to me that "combinaisons linéaires
d’applications du type" is referring to the set of all _linear combinations_ of functions of that type, _not_ to the space "composed of" functions of that type.

Comment: @david-c-ulrich Yeah now that I read it again it makes much more sense, but I read it fast at first and I completely missed that sentence... I guess it sounds pretty clear to you because you had to read every word carefully, but the phrasing is quite unusual compared to other exam papers, which is why I didn't see it at first :)

Comment: @ThéoCheynel a Small prepa, i'm at ISAE-ENSMA now

Answer (score 3):

Answer : the exam paper actually specified that $F$ is the vector space $\textit{spanned}$ by those functions. My bad !